# Make a search engine

Tags: code-golf, string, array

You need to make a program, that when giving a list and a string, searches on the list for items that contains the string.

Examples:

```
Input: th [thing, awesome, potato, example]
Output: thing (Because it starts with "th")

Input: ing [thing, potato]
Output: thing (Because it ends with "ing")

Input: tat [thing, potato]
Output: potato (Because it contains "tat")

Input: tat [tato, potato]
Output: tato, potato (If there are 2 or more results matching, print all of them)
```

Remember, this is code golf, so the shortest code wins.

### Leaderboard

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 72079; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 48934; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    if (/<a/.test(lang)) lang = jQuery(lang).text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang > b.lang) return 1;
    if (a.lang < b.lang) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Winners by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The spec shouldn't be explained in the answers

Comment: Did you mean "contains" the other substring?

Comment: Yup, that's right.

Answer (score 3):

## [TeaScript](http://github.com/vihanb/teascript), 4 bytes

```
F@Iσ
```

Output is cast to string.

[Try it online](http://vihan.org/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22F@I%CF%83%22&inputs=%5B%22%5B%5C%22tato%5C%22,%20%5C%22potato%5C%22%5D%22,%22%5C%22tat%5C%22%22%5D&opts=%7B%22ev%22:true,%22debug%22:false%7D)

### Explanation

```
F@  // Filter input 1
 Iσ // Includes input 2
```

Comment: Downvote and no comments?

Comment: Downgoats and no comments.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript ES6, 32 bytes

```
(s,a)=>a.filter(e=>~e.search(s))
```

33 bytes if the string might contain regexp metacharacters:

```
(s,a)=>a.filter(e=>~e.indexOf(s))
```

Comment: The spec is blurry enough, so I 'm not concerned about this ... but if the string can be *any* string and not just letters, you sholud use `indexoOf` instead of `search`

Comment: @edc65 Yes, I wasn't sure whether to mention that.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, <s>42</s> 36 bytes

```
lambda i,a:filter(lambda v:i in v,a)
```

Thanks to [muddyfish](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32686/muddyfish) for saving 6 bytes

Test:

```
a=lambda i,a:filter(lambda v:i in v,a)
a('th', ['thing', 'awesome', 'potato', 'example']) # ['thing']
a('ing', ['thing', 'potato'])                      # ['thing']
a('tat', ['thing', 'potato'])                      # ['potato']
a('tat', ['tato', 'potato'])                       # ['tato', 'potato']
```

Comment: Sometimes the right answer is boring. `lambda i,a:[v for v in a if i in v]` (35)

Comment: Regex please...

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 5 bytes

```
f}zTQ
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%7DzTQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=th%0A%5B%22thing%22%2C+%22awesome%22%2C+%22potato%22%2C+%22example%22%5D%0Atat%0A%5B%22tato%22%2C+%22potato%22%5D&debug=0&input_size=2).

Filters the input list by if the input string is in it.

Comment: Could you explain it?

Comment: @Alex82 sure, adding!

Answer (score 1):

### vim, 13

```
dd:v/\V<C-r>"<BS>/d<cr>
```

Expects input as

```
th
thing
awesome
potato
example
```

Outputs on separate lines.

```
dd      delete first line into " (default) register
:v/     apply to every line that doesn't match the following regexp...
\V        "very nomagic" - strips chars of their special regex meaning
<C-r>"    paste contents of " register into the command
<BS>      remove the trailing newline from the first line
/d      ... delete the lines
```

Comment: Doesn't this remove all matches (can't test right now)

Comment: @Seeq Sorry, my explanation is wrong. `:v` operates on all lines that do *not* match.

Comment: That would make more sense. Anyways, another feature of vim that I did not know about (+1)

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 49 bytes

```rkt
(λ(l s)(filter-map(curryr string-contains? s)l))
```

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w), 5 bytes

```
b@t!W
```

### Explanation

````
ba      % Implicit inputs
  b     % Access the second operand
   @    % Show two operands (yields [b,b,a])
      W % Select everything in a that fullfills this condition:
    t   % Trim everything in the current item
        % that appears in the input
        % Yields ([b,b.trim(a)])
     !  % Negate this result, determining whether
        % the input is a subset of the current item

        % Keeping all of the items that fullfill
        % this condition yields a list by default
```
````

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 47 bytes

```
a=input()
print[x for x in input()if x in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Bash, 27 bytes

```
tr \  \\n<<<${@:2}|fgrep $1
```

Sample run:

```
llama@llama:...code/shell/ppcg72079search$ ./search.sh th thing awesome potato example
thing
```

With multiple outputs, they will be on separate lines.

```
tr \  \\n   replace spaces with newlines (equivalent to tr ' ' '\n')
<<<${@:2}   ... with STDIN as all but first argument
|fgrep $1   fgrep for first argument (fgrep is grep w/ "fixed" string, not regex)
```

Answer (score 0):

## sh, 5 bytes

Accepts a list of words on stdin, one per line, and a search string as command line argument.

```
fgrep
```

This submisson should be valid by the rules on [scoring builtin functions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7205/on-scoring-builtin-functions).

Answer (score 0):

## , 4 chars / 5 bytes

```
í⒡ăî
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=%5B%60ing%60%2C%5B%60thing%60%2C%60potato%60%5D%5D&code=%C3%AD%E2%92%A1%C4%83%C3%AE)</kbd>

Simple.

## Explanation

Filter input array by string input.

Answer (score 0):

## R, <s>38</s> 28 bytes

```
function(x,y)grep(y,x,,,T,T)
```

simply a wrapper for `grep`, with value = `TRUE` to return the value [not a logical flag], and fixed (to allow regex-like strings to be searched and not processed as `regex`.

*edit* - 10 bytes by passing empty arguments to allow positional matching

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 29 bytes

```
Select[#2,StringContainsQ@#]&
```

Very simple.